# Typescript error in node_modules (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, eslint

I updated my project from React 17 to 18, I upgraded almost all my libs and fixed almost all errors that appeared.

But now I got this error in @reduxjs/toolkit :

```
ERROR in node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/query/fetchBaseQuery.ts:40:57
TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
    38 |  * Avoids storing `fetch` in a closure, in order to permit mocking/monkey-patching.
    39 |  */
  > 40 | const defaultFetchFn: typeof fetch = (...args) => fetch(...args)
       |                                                         ^^^^^^^
    41 |
    42 | const defaultValidateStatus = (response: Response) =>
    43 |   response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299
```

I don't know why it checks the node_modules folder, here is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/types",
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*"
  ],
  "types": []
}
```

I don't know if it's a eslint issue but I added ignorePatterns and .eslintignore just in case :

```
    "ignorePatterns": [
        "node_modules/",
        "**/node_modules/",
        "/**/node_modules/*",
        "out/",
        "dist/",
        "build/"
    ],
```

.eslintignore :

```
/**/node_modules/*
node_modules/
```

I also added resolution for @types/react in my package.json as I saw in another post

I tried to delete node_modules then reinstall, tried a 'yarn cache clean', tried to delete yarn.lock but still got this error.